# Uniform Distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study

Suppose we want to bid on a piece of land when one other bidder is interested. The seller announced that the highest bid in excess of \$10,000 will be accepted. Assume that the competitor's bid $X$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed between \$10,000 and \$15,000.

1. Suppose you bid $12,000. What is the probability yours will be accepted?
2. What amount should you bid to maximize the probability that you get the property.

My approach to this problem is as follows:

Opponent's mean bid = \$12,500

Opponent's Std Dev of bid = (\$15,000-\$10,000) / 6 = \$833.33

12000-12500 = -500

-500/833.33 = -0.6

Zscore = 0.27425

27.425% that the 12000 bid will be accepted?

Comment: What on earth does the question have to do with _normal_ distributions as you start off in your very first sentence, and why are you calculating z-scores at all? If the competitor's bid is **uniformly** distributed (your words, not mine) between 10,000 and 15,000, the probability that your bid of 12,000 will be higher than your (single) competitor's bid $X$ is $$P\{X < 12000\} = \frac{12000-10000}{15000-10000} = 0.4$$ and to maximize your chances of getting the property, you should bid 15,000 or more.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense it seems i was trying to overcomplicate it using a model that we used in class for something else.

Thanks for the response